# @PostConstruct method isn't being called during application server initalitization

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb

I've just been assigned to fix a Java EE application and I'm somewhat new to this. I have the following bean:

```
@Named
@ApplicationScoped
public class Configuration implements Serializable {

   public Configuration() {
   }

   @PostConstruct
   public void loadParams() {

       // inserted break point in next line
       SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
       URL resourceUrl = ResourceLocator.getResource(ARCHIVO_CONFIGURACION);
       // More code...
   }
}
```

I understand this bean will be initialized when the container is started (in this case jboss 7) and the *loadParams* method will be called once all dependences are injected. But after debugging I realized that neither the contructor nor the method are being called. What am I missing? Is there another configuration file for this task that I'm not taking into consideration? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out there was a problem with the *beans.xml* file. It was malformed and now the beans constructor and the *loadParams* method are being called:

This was the problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:s="urn:java:ee"
       xmlns:security="urn:java:org.jboss.seam.security"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">
....
```

Notice a **":"** is missing at the *xsi:schemaLocation* between the adresses.

Answer (score 1):

An **@ApplicationScoped** annotation tells the container that this bean will be single for the entire application.

I think if you want this Bean to be created at **startup** you should use the **@Eager** annotation as well.

Comment: So under the current configuration I have, when should the loadParams method be called?

Comment: If you use "@Named @ApplicationScoped @Eager" it should be called at application startup. If you let only "@Named @ApplicationScoped", it will be executed at first bean access.